# Selection sort algorithm

Tags: go

I am just trying to use Go so I will be thankful for all remarks and corrections:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func selectionSort(a []int) []int {

    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {

        min := i

        for j:= i + 1; j < len(a); j++ {
            if a[j] < a[min] {
                min = j;
            }
        }

        var tmp int = a[i]
        a[i] = a[min]
        a[min] = tmp
    }

    return a
}

func main() {

    values := []int { 5, 8, 4, 1, 7,  2, 3, 6 }
    result := selectionSort(values)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @coderodde said, get rid of that return and try to use `algoutils` package. That being said (there's no much about it), I'd **GO** with this version:

```
package main
// try using algoutils so that you can make use of Swap later
import (
    "fmt"
    "algoutils"
)

func selectionSort(array []int) {  // get rid of that ugly type declarator

    for i := 0; i < len(array) - 1; i++ {
        min := i
        for j := i + 1; j < len(array) - 1; j++ {
            if array[j] < array[min] {
                min = j
            }
        }
        algoutils.Swap(array, i, min)
    }
}

func main() {

    array := []int{5, 8, 4, 1, 7,  2, 3, 6}
    fmt.Println("Unsorted array: ", array)
    selectionSort(array)
    fmt.Println("Sorted array: ", array)
}
```

As a side-note, **variable names** should be as clear as possible:

`func selectionSort(a []int)` -> here it's clear `a` it's an array, but wouldn't be simpler if you'd just call it `array []int` ?

Comment: DON'T use algoutils. Use a tuple assignment.

Answer (score 7):

On Stack Overflow duplicate questions are closed.

For your question, a search of Code Review Stack Exchange for "[go] selection sort" finds, amongst others,

[Selection sort algorithm with increasing/decreasing sort options](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/117083/13970)

which has several detailed answers that address your question. For example, the code for [my answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/117615/13970), simplified for ascending order only, is

```
// selectionSort sorts the array a into ascending order.
// The selection sort algorithm is an in-place comparison sort
// with O(n*n) time complexity.
func selectionSort(a []int) {
    for i, x := range a[:len(a)-1] {
        k := i
        for j, y := range a[i+1 : len(a)] {
            if x > y {
                // out of order
                k = i + 1 + j
                x = y
            }
        }
        a[k], a[i] = a[i], x
    }
}
```

My code is idomatic Go and it's more than twice as fast as your code when running a Go benchmark which sorts 1024 random integers.

```
BenchmarkDemas           300       4894852 ns/op
BenchmarkPeterSO        1000       2339806 ns/op
```

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

You sort the arrays in-place (as it should be), so you don't really need to return the input array back from the sort function. I would remove the return type declarator (**`[]int`** after the argument list), and remove the **`return`** statement.